# DSolve not giving a solution

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

[image]

I tried solving this but no result, I tried eliminating the initial condition, replace the zeroes in boundary condition but nothing is working.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Areeba Rao, Pl post the Ques in Mathematica format

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that this system of ODEs has a symbolic solution?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful